# PDFAnnotation Radiobutton don't change background color or don't display value

Tags: swift, radio-button, background-color, pdfkit, pdf-annotations

I use PDFKit in iOS as PDF renderer and I have problem with background color in radio button.

I iterate all PDF annotations on all pages in the document.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  //let pdfData = ... received data from file storage ...
  if let document = PDFDocument(data: pdfData) {
    for i in 0...document.pageCount {
      if let page = document.page(at: i) {
         for annot in page.annotations {
           if annot.widgetControlType == .radioButtonControl {
              annot.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           }
         }         
       }
     }
   }
}
```

When I set the background color, nothing happens. 
But when I try to set the background color to the type of *Text annotation*, the color changes.

The difference between the Radio button and the Text annotation is in its type.
The Radio button has a *widgetFieldType == .button* and the Text has a *widgetFieldType == .text*.

I think this is the reason why it doesn't work.

Next I try to remove annotation, change his background color and add again. This also doesn't work.

```
if annot.widgetControlType == .radioButtonControl {
  page.removeAnnotation(annot)
  annot.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  page.addAnnotation(annot)
}
```

But when I create a new instance of PDFAnnotaion, and I add it to the page, it works.

```
if annot.widgetControlType == .radioButtonControl {
  page.removeAnnotation(annot)
  let newAnnot = PDFAnnotation(bounds: annot.bounds, forType: .widget, withProperties: nil)
  newAnnot.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  newAnnot.widgetStringValue = annot.widgetStringValue
  page.addAnnotation(newAnnot)
}
```

The big problem is that the value of this Radio button is not displayed, even though it contains the value itself. 
If in another method I get all the values from PDF annotations, there is also the right value from this radio button. 
The Radio button contains the value, only it is displayed.

I tried to copy all the properties PDF annotation from the *annot* to *newAnnot*, but it didn't help.

How to properly change the background color of the Radio button and display its value?

Comment: Hi puty did you find out the answer to your question

Comment: Hi Codicil, since PDFKit has a lot of other bugs, I finally decided on another solution. In my case the pdfs are not large (number of pages) so I render them asynchronously into images and manually render the active layer with controls above the images.

Comment: By the way what widget string value was assigned to your radio button,